# Block not loading some times in observer magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

Some times load more functionality is not loading while debugging I found sometimes the block is not loaded. I tried two but not working.

As I've noticed it is easy to reproduce issue after login is mostly loadmore auto scroll is not coming.

After login the block is not loading into observer

block name : Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct

Observer name : layout_generate_blocks_after

Event Name : layout_generate_blocks_after

Also I've installed the new plugin for infinity scroll lof/magepow scroll working fine with mysql search engine and but not working with elastic search engine in magento 2.3.4
no after login issue its search engine issue any suggestion how to solve this issue.

```
    private function getCategoryProductListBlock(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/satish.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info(102);
        $productListBlock = $this->layout->getBlock('category.products.list');
        //$observer->getLayout()->getBlock('category.products.list');
        //not loading when the loadmore is not coming the block
//        $logger->info(json_encode($productListBlock->getData()));
        if (!$productListBlock) {
            $logger->info('106');
            foreach ($observer->getLayout()->getAllBlocks() as $block) {
                if ($block instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct) {
                    $productListBlock = $block;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return $productListBlock;
    }
```

Comment: what event are you listening too?

Comment: layout_generate_blocks_after : event name

block name : Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct

Observer name : layout_generate_blocks_after

After login the block is not loading into observer

not coming under the foreach 
$observer->getLayout()->getAllBlocks() --- here is the issue after login

Comment: any idea why not coming under the loop after login